# Need to make a .bat file to stop and then restart a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

We have a Dexis dental xray installation that uses SQL Server 2005 as the database. In order to back up the data, I have to open SQL Server Configuration Manager, stop the database, and then run Backup Exec. When it finishes, I have to restart the database.

I need to be able to automate this in Backup Exec 16, so I figured I would create a batch file that runs before the backup to stop the database. I could then execute a second batch to restart.

Can anyone give me a Dos box command that will stop and then restart a SQL Server database?

Thanks.

---

I thought that backing up the MDF and LDF files only backed up the database, and would not back up the actual data.  I also thought that you had to stop the database in order to be given access to the data.

Amazingly, Dexis tech support people have no white papers, no protocols, and no suggestions on how to back up the data.

What is the proper method for backing the entire thing up so that if the server melts down, we can easily recreate the database AND the data?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by `stop the database`

Comment: Why do you need to stop anything to do a database backup?

Answer (score 6):

On the WIndows command prompt, just use the `NET STOP` command to stop the `MSSQLSERVER` service, and `NET START` to restart it again:

```
NET STOP MSSQLSERVER
.....
REM do your backup here
.....
NET START MSSQLSERVER
```

**Update:** however, copying around the SQL Server database files (`.mdf` and `.ldf`) to do a server backup is **not** the recommended way of doing this.

Instead, you should use SQL Server's own `BACKUP DATABASE ...` functionality to generate `.bak` files, and then include *those* `.bak` files in your file-based backup and skip the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files

Comment: Is there any way to just stop one database instead of the entire service?

Comment: @EmmettKelly: no - you can *only* stop the whole service (the whole **instance**) - not a single database on an instance

Comment: Let me get this straight, you are stopping the Sal service.  How in the world are you supposed to back up the database then?

Comment: @Greg: yes - because if you read the OP's question closely, he isn't doing a "proper" SQL Server backup (that would require the SQL Server engine to be running - I agree), but he's using a third-party tool to just copy the files around. That's definitely not the best way to do it, but if you really want to copy away the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files - you have to stop the SQL Server service - right?? Your downvote is definitely **not** warranted!

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't aware OP was trying to do file backup.

Comment: What about detaching the database? That is possible using SQL statements (and `sqlcmd` on the command line) if I'm not mistaken and if the database is detached, a file copy should be possible, shouldn't it?

Comment: .@a_horse_with_no_name: possible: yes - recommended: not really. One should really use the proper BACKUP DATABASE functionality

Comment: Does Backup Database back up the actual database structure as well as the data?

Perhaps the better question is if we're running Backup Exec 16, (which they claim is not compatible with SQL 2005), how do we backup the database structure as well as the data?

Comment: The structure and the data is in the MDF. You can't store data without a structure to put it in

Comment: @EmmettKelly: SQL Server backup is always a **whole** backup - **ALL** the database objects (tables, views, stored procedures, etc.) **AND** all the data

Answer (score 1):

I am totally agreed with @marc_s answer but have added few more things. We will require Admin permission for such action, so added that check. Here is my batch file -

```
@echo off
if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)

NET STOP  MSSQL$SQL2017 /y
NET START MSSQL$SQL2017
timeout 5
NET STOP  SQLAgent$SQL2017
NET START SQLAgent$SQL2017
timeout 5
NET STOP  SQLBrowser
NET START SQLBrowser
```

Have tested that with Win 10, powershell is used for checking admin rights.